# Google Audience reports using php

Tags: php, google-analytics, report

One of my client needs to use the Google Audience reports using his site.
can someone give a idea to do that please?

I have changed the following code

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

into

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
```

after that analytic account says 
"Your Demographics and Interest Reports have been enabled, but your Analytics tracking code does not include the necessary support to show them".
 can some one help on this.....

Comment: Can you provide some additional context around what you're trying to accomplish and what you have tried? Have you tried googling implementing google analytics php?

Comment: Hi Blexy,well  he needs to have Demographics, Age, Gender, Interests and affinity categories. yes i tried googling, but i couldn't find that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you fulfill all of theese criterias?

> To take advantage of Remarketing with Google Analytics, you need to:
>
> - Agree to the Google Analytics Terms of Service (please make sure to review them fully as they may have changed since you last viewed them).
> - Agree to the Google Analytics for Display Advertisers Policy
> - Update your privacy policy and include an appropriate description of your use of remarketing in online advertising.
> - Update your Analytics tracking code by adding a single line.
> - Have at least one active Google AdWords account that is linked to your Analytics account.
> - Have an active Google Analytics account with the Edit permission.

When you create a remarketing list, you can share it with a single AdWords account. If you want to use the list in more than one AdWords account, then you need to recreate the list for each account.

Above list is taken from: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2611270?hl=en&ref_topic=2611283

Comment: Also, are you using Universal Analytics or Classic Analytics? This has an impact on if you can or cannot use re-marketing tags. Universal Analytics properties does not currently support the dc.js tag.

Comment: how can i find the difference between classic and universal?.bit confused. can you help on this please?

Comment: If you look at your source code, search for gaq.push or ga.js. If you find this code, you have the Classic Analytics. If you find something like analytics.js, you have Universal.